Getting error of @babel/helper-annotate-as-pure while doing yarn
I got strange issue only since this morning, while doing yarn I got this issue Request failed.
I thought it is related to babel repo so I have created a bug over it's repo https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/17029 but as they mentioned it is an issue either with the yarnpkg registry or with your package manager.
I have already added configuration over github issues and other environments are there
node -v

v19.9.0

yarn -v

1.22.22

npm -v

9.6.3

Other dependencies are
Node: 19.9.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: yarn 1.22.22
OS: linux x64

Angular: 16.2.12
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Requesting suggestion on same. Thanks in advance
I have already tried below steps

yarn -rf node_modules
yarn rm yarn.lock
yarn cache clean
curl https://registry.yarnpkg.com
yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
yarn install --no-cache

but no luck
